# Border doesn't encapsulate all thumbnail elements on screen resizing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

DEMO: https://www.bootply.com/C5khaYe5Yf

My issue is that when I resize my window to accommodate larger devices (width > 900px) the thumbnail border encapsulates only the image and not the whole content of the thumbnail (h4 and p), there is no problem with smaller screen sizes though. I cannot exactly figure out what causes this behavior. How to make border encapsulate all elements on all screen sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Patrick, there's a CSS property called `overflow`. If you set the value to `hidden`, it will clip your content, which will keep the enclosed elements in your border. The reason why they're spilling over is because your content inside the "thumbnail" takes up more space than the thumbnail, and because the default value for the `overflow` property is visible, it is rendered outside of the border you created.

To learn more about the overflow property and its associated values you can checkout the MDN resource for it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).

I've included a link for you to see the `overflow` property in action. You can see it [here](https://www.codeply.com/go/Ax8Po1tP0s).